# Time taken for a body to reach a velocity of sqrt(a) from 0 under an acceleration a?

Tags: kinematics

Lets say body starts from rest and would like to attain a velocity of sqrt(a) , where a is the acceleration (constant) of the body.

By laws of motion we get t = 1/sqrt(a) which in the case of a --> 0 tends to infinity. But if we see the body has indeed reached the speed of sqrt(a) i.e 0 at t=0 itself.

Am I missing some thing here ?

Any pointers would be helpful !

Comment: Your units don't make sense. $[a]=\rm m/s^2$, so taking the square-root gives units of $[\sqrt a]=\rm \sqrt{m}/s$ which is not a velocity. You'll have to multiply by some distance (which should also satisfy the kinematics).

Comment: So if a = 16 m/sec^2, you want the velocity to be 4 m/sec?  If so, then that's NOT the root of the accel.  The units do not match up.

Comment: Kyle is the kwisatz haderach!

Comment: The problem is the units don't match up.  It's a trick question.

Comment: We already know that. By the way, what's a kwisatz haderach?

Comment: This question always makes sense in any fixed unit system. The problem is just dividing by zero, it's not any more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the acceleration is $a$ m/s$^2 \neq 0$, then the distance travelled after reaching a velocity of $\sqrt{a}$ m/s is always the same, namely $x =0.5$ m. Therefore, as the acceleration tends to zero, the time taken to reach this distance obviously tends to infinity, so your answer makes perfect sense. However, the same result cannot be applied directly to the limit $a = 0$, since then your naive application of the equations for $a\neq 0$ would be invalid. In this case Newton's laws tell you that the velocity is just $v(t) = 0$ for all time $t$. In particular, $v(0) = 0$, and therefore the time taken to reach a velocity of $0$ is trivially $0$.

Comment: Do you mean to say that v = u + at is meaningful for only a being non zero ?

Comment: No, I don't. If you apply $v = u + at$ to the case where $a = 0$, $u = 0$, then the answer is $v = 0$. So this tells you that the velocity is already zero. When $a\neq 0$, then you can divide by $\sqrt{a}$ to get $t = 1/\sqrt{a}$ for $v = \sqrt{a}$. Obviously the solution $t = 1/\sqrt{a}$ does not make sense for $a=0$, you are not allowed to divide by zero.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity has units of m/s and acceleration m/s² so the root of acceleration would be √m/s. This unit does not make any sense.

If you just want the numerical value, then v=a·t → √a=a·t then √a/a=t.

Comment: The numeric Values could be a and sqrt(a) right !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clarify the question. If it has an acceleration of a=0 it cannot attain a velocity of 1/sqrt(a).

Comment: It needs to attain a velocity of sqrt(a) which is 0 when a =0 and hence attainable. Also please add this response in comment !

Comment: it does attain a velocity of sqrt(a), its acceleration is 0, thus sqrt(0) is 0? It has 0 velocity if it started at rest and is non-accelerating.